# Alert jquery help, need its text to go inside of div/span

Tags: jquery, json

I have this script and would like to add it to a specific div.  Right now it just alerts with a popup window.

```
function getTime(zone, success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
        ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
    window[ud]= function(o){
        success && success(new Date(o.datetime));
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
        return s;
    })());
}

getTime('US\/Hawaii', function(time){
    // This is where you do whatever you want with the time:
    alert(time);
});
```

Comment: `success && success`? is this a new kind of `if` statement?

Comment: @undefined: `success` might be set to `false` and in JS, if I remember correctly, the `&&` short circuits. It's (somewhat confusing) shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

javascript:

```
$("div#specific_id").append(time);
```

html:

```
<div id="specific_id">the time will be added after this text</div>
```

I think you should see the documentation

**EDIT:** 
@Blender have make this helping snippet, to make everything clear: http://jsfiddle.net/eytkU/2/

Comment: I think you should see the documentation as well since your answer is wrong.

Comment: No, this answer is correct. If you use jQuery (like your tag says), this should work in every browser without bugs.

Comment: @user1477535: Before you get snobby, take some time to actually include jQuery to see what isn't working: http://jsfiddle.net/eytkU/2/

Comment: @Blender: thank you for the link, it makes everything clear :)